# Using MariaDB temporal tables with spring data jpa native query is not giving me the correct result

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

```
public interface PeseeRepository extends JpaRepository<Pesee, Integer> {
...
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM pesee FOR SYSTEM_TIME all WHERE id_pesage = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Pesee> findAllPeseeHystoryById(Integer id);
...
}
```

Log:

```
Hibernate: 
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    pesee FOR SYSTEM_TIME all 
WHERE
    id_pesage = ?
```

result of the native query in my program :
[image]

raw sql exemple:

```
    SELECT
    * 
FROM
    pesee FOR SYSTEM_TIME all 
WHERE
    id_pesage = 1879;
```

result in raw sql:

[image]

apparently the native jpa query does not return the same result as the standard sql query.

But detects the number of rows correctly.

Here is my question: How to make mariadb table versioning work in my spring boot application?
The goal is simply to return me history of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve my problem by going through a lower level query

https://javabydeveloper.com/spring-jdbctemplate-query-examples/#preparedstatementcreator

```
public class PeseeMapper implements RowMapper<Pesee> {

    private final OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    private final ZoneOffset zoneOffSet = ZoneOffset.of(String.valueOf(odt.getOffset()));


    @Override
    public Pesee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {


        return new Pesee(
          
                rs.getTimestamp("date_poids_1").toInstant().atOffset(zoneOffSet),
                rs.getInt("poids_1"),
                rs.getTimestamp("date_poids_2").toInstant().atOffset(zoneOffSet),
                rs.getInt("poids_2"),
                rs.getString("destination"),

                rs.getTimestamp("date_creation").toInstant().atOffset(zoneOffSet),
                rs.getTimestamp("date_modification").toInstant().atOffset(zoneOffSet),
                );
    }
}
```

```
public class PeseePreparedStatementCreator implements PreparedStatementCreator, SqlProvider {

    private String sql;
    private Integer param;

    public PeseePreparedStatementCreator(String sql, Integer param) {
        this.sql = sql;
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }


    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(getSql(), ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ps.setInt(1, param);
        return ps;
    }

}
```

```
@Repository
public class PeseeJDBC {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public List<Pesee> findAllPeseeHystoryById(Integer id) {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM pesee FOR SYSTEM_TIME all WHERE id_pesage = ? ORDER BY date_modification DESC";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(new PeseePreparedStatementCreator(sql, id), new PeseeMapper());
    }
}
```

this now returns me the correct result of a temporal table
[image]

For the Objects to recover I called on my service in PeseeJDBC and I transmitted it to PeseeMapper
Then in the PeseeMapper class I called findById from my transmitted service. (I did not add this in the example codes so as not to complicate the initial problem)
It's a bit wobbly at the architectural level but it's functional